# How to remove public from file url in laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

```
<a href="{{url('/storage/app/'.$attendee->pcustom_11)}}" target="_blank">
```

Preview Certificate

> output is https://www.example.com/public/storage/app/file.pdf

Comment: Is the document root for your site configuration pointing to the `public` folder of the project?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `asset()`;

Instead of using `url('/storage/app/'.$attendee->pcustom_11)` use `asset('/storage/app/'.$attendee->pcustom_11)`;

So it will look like this -

```
<a href="{{asset('/storage/app/'.$attendee->pcustom_11)}}" target="_blank">
```

Refer this part from laravel official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset) .

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: still, I have public in the output.